# Make multiple fields required if one option or another is checked jQuery Validate

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate, validation

In my form, new fields appear depending on which radio button option is required. I would like to validate those fields only if the corresponding radio button is required.

If the first option is selected, address, city, state, and zip are required.
If the 2nd option is selected, only date is required
If the 3rd option is selected, all of the fields above are required.

I have posted a fiddle here of what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/aEgk8/1/

What I would like to do is figure out a way to write a rule where a field is required if one option OR the other is checked. Something like

```
  address: {
   required: "#ship-address:checked or #ship-both:checked"
  },
  city: {
   required: "#ship-address:checked or #ship-both:checked"
  }
```

I also need to update the rule for the selects, so they are only required if one of the options is checked.  How can I do this? This is my first time trying to implement something like this so I'm  open to suggestions.

I am implementing this on a site that uses the 1.3.2 library (which I can't change or remove), and the show/hide on the fields will not work with that, so I have to run a newer library in parallel.  The show/hide functionality I have does not work when I only reference jQuery 1.3.2.

Here is my code:

```
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>       
            <script src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
            debug: true,
            success: "valid"
        });
            </script>                
            <script>var $j = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>                
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $j(document).ready(function() {
                $j.validator.addMethod("valueNotEquals", function(value, element, arg){
                  return arg != value;
                 }, "Please select a new shipping date.");
                 $j('#pancettaForm').change(function () {
                           $j('#address,#address2,#new-ship-date').hide();
                           if ($j('#ship-address').prop('checked')) {
                              $j('#address, #address2').show();
                           }
                           else if ($j('#ship-date').prop('checked')) {
                              $j('#new-ship-date').show();
                           }
                           else if ($j('#ship-both').prop('checked')) {
                              $j('#address, #address2, #new-ship-date').show();
                           }
                        });
                        $j( "#pancettaForm" ).validate({
                               rules: {
                                       address: {
                                               required: "#ship-address:checked"
                                       },
                                       newShip: {
                                               valueNotEquals: "- Select -"
                                       }
                               },
                               messages: {
                                       updateShip: {
                                               required: "Please tell us how you would like to update your order."
                                       },
                                       SelectName: {
                                               valueNotEquals: "Please select a new shipping date."
                                       }
                               }
                       });

            });


            </script>
```

and the HTML:

```
        <form name="pancettaForm" method="post" action="http://lizlantz.com/lcform.php" id="pancettaForm">
                <input type="hidden" value="Pancetta Order Update" name="subject"> 
                <input type="hidden" value="cookware/partners_10151_-1_20002" name="redirect">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                    <label for="updateShip">I'd like to:</label> 
                        <input id="ship-address" name="updateShip" type="radio" value="update-ship-address" class="required"/> Have pancetta shipped to a different address than my skillet<br />
                        <input id="ship-date" name="updateShip" type="radio" value="update-ship-date" class="required" /> Have pancetta shipped sooner than June 14, 2013 <br />
                        <input id="ship-both" name="updateShip" type="radio" value="update-both"  class="required"/> Make changes to both the shipping address and shipping date
                    </li>
                    <li>                
                    <label for="order-number"><em>*</em>Order Number (available in order confirmation email):</label> 
                        <input type="text" name="order-number" class="required">
                    </li>             
                    <li>                
                    <label for="full-name"><em>*</em>Recipient Full Name:</label> 
                        <input type="text" name="full-name" class="required">
                    </li>   
                    <li id="address" style="display: none;">
                        <label for="address">
                            <em>*</em>Address
                        </label> 
                        <input type="text" name="address">
                        <label for="address2">
                            Address Line 2
                        </label> 
                        <input type="text" name="address2">
                    </li>
                    <li id="address2" style="display: none;">
                        <label for="city">
                            <em>*</em>City
                        </label> 
                        <input type="text" name="city">
                        <label for="state">
                            <em>*</em>State
                        </label> 
                        <select name="state">
                            <option>- Select State -</option>                            
                            <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                            <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                            <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                            <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                            <option value="CA">California</option>
                            <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                            <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                            <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                            <option value="DC">District of Columbia</option>
                            <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                            <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                            <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                            <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                            <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                            <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                            <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                            <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                            <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                            <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                            <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                            <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                            <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                            <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                            <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                            <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                            <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                            <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                            <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                            <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                            <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                            <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                            <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                            <option value="NY">New York</option>
                            <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                            <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                            <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                            <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                            <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                            <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                            <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                            <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                            <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                            <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                            <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                            <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                            <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                            <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                            <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                            <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                            <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                            <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                        </select>
                        <label for="zip">
                            <em>*</em>Zip Code
                        </label> 
                        <input type="text" name="zip">
                    </li>
                    <li id="new-ship-date" style="display: none;">
                        <label for="New Ship Date"><em>*</em>New Ship Date (Saturday-Tuesday delivery not available):</label>                 
                        <select name="newShip" id="newShip">
                            <option>- Select -</option>
                            <option value="Wednesday, May 22">Wednesday, May 22</option>
                            <option value="Thursday, May 23">Thursday, May 23</option>
                            <option value="Friday, May 24">Friday, May 24</option>
                            <option value="Wednesday, May 29">Wednesday, May 29</option>
                            <option value="Thursday, May 30">Thursday, May 30</option>
                            <option value="Friday, May 31">Friday, May 31</option>
                            <option value="Wednesday, June 5">Wednesday, June 5</option>
                            <option value="Thursday, June 6">Thursday, June 6</option>
                            <option value="Friday, June 8">Friday, June 8</option>
                            <option value="Wednesday, June 12">Wednesday, June 12</option>
                            <option value="Thursday, June 13">Thursday, June 13</option>
                            <option value="Friday, June 14">Friday, June 14 </option>
                            <option value="Wednesday, June 19">Wednesday, June 19</option>
                            <option value="Thursday, June 20">Thursday, June 20</option>
                            <option value="Friday, June 21">Friday, June 21</option>
                        </select>                            
                    </li>                       
                    <li>
                        <label for="phone">
                            <em>*</em>Phone (for delivery questions)
                        </label> 
                        <input type="text" name="phone" class="required">
                    </li>               
                </ul>
                       <input type="submit" id="button" name="submit"  value="Update Pancetta">

              </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
address: {
  required: {
    depends: function(element) {
      return $('#ship-address').is(':checked') || $('#ship-both').is(':checked');
    }
  }
},
city: {
  required: {
    depends: function(element) {
      return $('#ship-address').is(':checked') || $('#ship-both').is(':checked');
    }
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aEgk8/4/

As for the selects, I'm not sure which ones you refer, but the idea is the same, based on dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may be an option you are looking for (although I have not tested this in your version of jQuery): http://jqueryvalidation.org/category/methods/#example:-makes-details-required-only-if-#other-is-checked

From the jquery.validation documentation:

> Example: Makes details required only if #other is checked.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Makes details required only if #other is checked.</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/site-demos.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="myform">
        <label for="other">Check to make next field required</label>
        <input id="other" type="checkbox">
        <br>
        <input id="details" name="details">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Validate!">
    </form>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

    <script>

    // just for the demos, avoids form submit
    jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
        debug: true,
        success: "valid"
    });

    $( "#myform" ).validate({
        rules: {
            details: {
                required: "#other:checked"
            }
        }
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This solution, while repetitive if you have many fields, is still cleaner than using the `depends` method mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I think just adding a `,` would help:

```
address: {
 required: "#ship-address:checked, #ship-both:checked"
},
city: {
 required: "#ship-address:checked, #ship-both:checked"
}
```